# OData4J and AppEngine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, odata, odata4j

Does anyone have a very simple example of using OData4J and GAE?

In the OData4J site there is a stub project for use in GAE...but doesn't really show how to expose entities out of the datastore as odata entities.

I may be missing something with that stub project(I'm sure I am)...but just need a little jump start on how to publish my persisted entities.

Thanks
MJD

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at http://code.google.com/p/odata-appengine/

Maybe it's just what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

the [odata4j-appengine](http://code.google.com/p/odata4j/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fodata4j-appengine) sample project in the repository shows how to expose existing appengine datastore kinds as odata open-typed entities.

See [appengine-web.xml](http://code.google.com/p/odata4j/source/browse/trunk/odata4j-appengine/war/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml) for how it's configured.

If you need any additional help, feel free to post to our discussion group at [odata4j-discuss](http://groups.google.com/group/odata4j-discuss).

Thanks,
- John

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, it looks like no one has written and published such example code yet. [google has only 127 results for odata4j "app engine"](http://www.google.com/q=odata4j+%22app+engine%22), and the vast majority are unrelated mentions that happen to be on the same page.

so, you may be in unexplored territory here, at least as far as the internet is concerned. if you do end up writing example code yourself, feel free to post it here so others can benefit!